# Need help or idea to cleaning folders

Tags: jsf, jakarta-ee, jboss5.x

I have a problem like below , can any body give some idea how to solve the issue!!

Me using JSF for my project, in backbean in a method where I ought to create a folders in a specific folder on the (Jboss) server system. Just before the session is about to destroyed I need to delete those folder on the file system of server.

How to do this one ?
I cant implement HttpSessionListner for the backbean as in its constructor me doing a lot of other stuff.
  Not sure how to resolve this problem , can any body give any good idea to handle this ?

Thanks in advance.
~Shyam

Answer (score 1):

You have to think about a solution which will work even when the server will crash. I would implement a job/batch to delete all folders which are older than a certain amount of time (let's say 1 day for instance). Testing if a folder is enough old to be deleted or not is probably no problem and depends on your specific application. (e.g. you can read the creation date of the folder, or create the folder with a given name containing the date when the folder was created)

Comment: thanks a lot Laurent. So you dont see any possibility using HttpSessionListner or any other ?

Comment: A `HttpSessionListener` could also work. But what happens if the server crash before the session is destroyed? You would have remaining folder. But that could be also an alternative, if you can delete all folders at startup. This way you handle crashes too. But my preference goes to a solution which is not coupled with the session mechanism.

Comment: Thanks a lot Laurent. The problem when i used HttpSessionListener, by the time i call sessionDestory session object is becoming null. Hence i am not able to access the stored object inside the session.

Comment: any more suggestions